# ruby on rails could not find ffi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

i see [this](http://i1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb354/elieobeid7/untitled.gif) often when working with `mysql` or `mysql2`, i tried to install `ffi` but it makes no difference, could you please help solving this issue

i tried `gem install ffi`, `bundle install ffi` i tried many stuff, just would not work! when do `rake db:create` i will see the error, i have the latest [rails installer](http://i1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb354/elieobeid7/untitled.gif) if i use [ruby installer](http://railsinstaller.org) instead, i'll get many other errors like: you need the dev toolkit to build this gem and i install the toolkit and still the the error therefore i prefer to stick with rails installer,

**EDIT**:

lets say i typed `bundle install mysql` i see the error: `make sure that ffi installation succeeds before you continue` or something like that, the thing is, if i don't solve `ffi error` i'll be stuck with sqlite, because i bet that mongodb, couchdb, mysql, mysql2, postgeres, whatever... all need `ffi`, i don't know what `ffi` is but it's seems to be very important thing

Comment: `ffi` is the foreign function interface for interfacing with native code. I'm not sure if it works on Windows (even if it does, things have much better compatibility on Linux and you should probably be deploying on a Linux server).

Comment: Second using Linux for development, using Windows is an uphill battle if you don't know what your doing. Try running `gem install ffi --version='1.0.9'`

Comment: @BenAlpert, yes ben, if the `ffi` error is not solved i will develop everything using sqlite and when i deploy the app, i'll install mysql gem from ssh, i will have no other option!!

Comment: @DevinM i tried `gem install ffi --version='1.0.9`, it makes no difference, and my pc that i work on right does not have enough ram for virtualbox lol! :)

Comment: The problem I ran into was that the `1.9.1` gem was pulled (yanked) (or at least it couldn't be found anymore), but was locked in my `Gemfile.lock`. Uninstalling `gem uninstall ffi --version='1.9.1'` and running `bundle update` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had an issue with ffi myself (in fact I hadn't even heard of it before your post), although I did have bizarre gem issues when working on Windows.

Your problem seems to be this:

C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/ror/selvista/mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11

In particular, there's a line in your error code:

```
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in 'pwd'
```

I think you need to move your ror folder somewhere else, like C:\ror, something without spaces in it.

If you look higher up:

```
Makefile:160: warning: overriding commands for target 'C:/Documents'
```

It thinks your folder is just C:/Documents

Comment: i wanted to ask about that but i thought that it was a silly question lol :) because if gems were like libraries in python, they would need to be installed in C right? and not on the desktop... let me try that and I'll tell you what happens :)

Comment: now when i run rake 'db:create' i see 'rake aborted, can't convert nil into hash ' *tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config*

Comment: hey man it worked!! i uninstalled everything and reinstalled them, the default folder is C:/sites and i cannot use any other folder :D

Comment: oh no, the problem is not solved yet but I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get back to you sooner :(  What happened afterwards?  The reason I suggested the no spaces was because I seem to recall the Ruby installer saying it must be installed in a directory with no spaces (it recommended C:\Ruby).  Was it still having the same problem with ffi, or a different issue?

Comment: Note, I just went back to my Windows box and I don't have ffi installed (but use mysql).  Is ffi listed in the gem file?

Comment: nevermind it worked! first my ror folder is `C:\sites` and it won't work if i create projects outside this folder...then i had to download mysql 6 C connector from dev.mysql.com and copy a file into the ruby folder...it worked thanks :) i forgot to comment on this question again and say it really worked :D